# fabric keeps asking for password

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I have fab file which contains

```
env['hosts'] = ['localhost']
env['user'] = 'code'
env['password'] = 'searce'

def mk_dirtree():
    sudo("mkdir %s" % PROJECT_DIR)
    sudo("chown -R code:code %s" % PROJECT_DIR)
    run("mkdir -p %s" % (PROJECT_DIR + '/www/static'))
    sudo("chown -R www-data:www-data %s" % (PROJECT_DIR + '/www'))
```

now when I do `fab mk_dirtree` I am constantly prompt for `[localhost] Login password for 'code':`

I am running this on an ec2 instance to which I am connecting via ssh using key, and password login for ssh is disabled

**EDIT:**
I think fabric is first doing `ssh code@localhost` but that wont work since password sshing is disabled

Answer (score 4):

If you really want and need to use `run()` instead of `local()` you can add your SSH public key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file of your user account.

This would look something like this:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

This solution will circumvent the login password prompt of your local machine. Of course, you'd have to do this for each local machine where you run your fabfile on.

Comment: This really helped me out on my iMac. I am developing my run() commands and this allows for rapid test of those commands on my localhost.

Answer (score 1):

The `run()` and `sudo()` operations are carried out via ssh.  If you want to run a command on the localhost you should look into using `local()` instead:

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/api/core/operations.html?highlight=sudo#fabric.operations.local

On that same page are the docs for `run()` and `sudo()` which both refer to the fact they run on a "remote host" which infers that they will be run via ssh.